# Run method at specific time MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, scheduling

I'm developing a MVC application and it has a method, which should have to run end of the day. I do not have the access to windows task scheduler and implementing windows service is not possible. (Because deployed package should have to give to different customers and they have their own servers. In this case we not gonna deploy windows service or use task scheduler)

Please tell me is there any method to execute some method at specific time.
I saw there are methods which are use timer. But the problem is this job should have to do only one time in the day and process will not take longer than 1 minute.

If we use timer, resources will allocate to timer service and it is not a good method as i guess, because this method run only one time in the day. (Process is running in other 23 hours and 59 minutes and it is wasting resources. I guess timer concept is ok, if process is running in every 5,10 minutes)

Please give me direction....

Comment: Take a look at quartz job scheduler.

Comment: "*and implementing windows service is not possible*", why it is not possible ? When project is deployed to your customers it can install windows service as a part of deployment process... If you want to execute method on *customer's machine* once a day, you'd have to have some long-running app anyway

Comment: Take a look at HangFire, its designed for the purpose you describe and can fire off a job/method at a given time: http://hangfire.io/

Comment: @Fabjan : There are thousands of customers which are using our applicatoin. So how to do this one by one? We simply need to deploy the package and run the system as well as the scheduler smoothly.

Comment: I used quartz. It is working fine with startup.cs. But the problem is i cannot initialize a class object in "execute" method, which is the method implementation is in some other project. (IJob has a method called "Execute") unfortunately it is not given facilities to copy paste the code, what i did up-to now by stack-overflow in comment section. I red few articles which contains, it wont be able to initialize other class object inside startup cs or application_start() method.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use `Quartz.Net`

this is a good example to use it :

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net

Comment: Quartz.net is just a library, it's not a windows process and it doesn't solve the problem by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you already have a database. Create a table with a single datetime field named LastRun. Save in this field the last date and time your method has been executed.

In your MVC application on Session Start or on Application start compare LastRun datetime with current datetime and decide if you are going to perform the above mentioned method. After the method has been executed update the LastRun value.

Comment: simply I check with below code inside application_start() because this is day end process and should run at sharp 12 midnight.
<c# code>  
 DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/22");

            if (DateTime.Today == dt)
            {
                int x = 5;

            }
      <c# code>
I changed my local machine time to 2016/09/21 11:59pm and wait till trigger the bolow code.(add a break point inside "if" block) But it doent trigger.

Comment: The disadvantage of the above proposed method is that you will need an new application or session start event to trigger it.